# Survey on Quantum error correction

Tags: reference-request, quantum-computing, quantum-information, coding-theory

Are there any standard recent survey articles on quantum error correction (and may be including fault Tolerant computing)? The most standard ones that many people refer to are [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9705052.pdf) and [this](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph229/notes/chap7.pdf). Both of them being relatively old, are missing some standard things such as Surface codes, codes comng from homology or LDPC codes. I am looking for survey paper giving indication of currently where do we stand.

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

[Quantum Error Correction by Todd Brun](https://scirate.com/arxiv/1910.03672)

[Quantum Error Correction: An Introductory Guide by Joschka Roffe](https://scirate.com/arxiv/1907.11157)

For surface codes, [Dan Browne's lecture notes](https://sites.google.com/site/danbrowneucl/teaching/lectures-on-topological-codes-and-quantum-computation) might help.